# How do I fix these errors in Overleaf?

Tags: errors

I'm using a forked version of this [resume template](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV) (huge thanks to posquit0!). I am a TeX noob, knowing only enough to muck up this beautiful resume template with my petty customizations!

I want the ability to generate the document locally (and ultimately to HTML as well as PDF), but right now the only way I can build it is on Overleaf. I get the same error when I try to generate it locally, but Overleaf generates the pdf despite the errors in the log. Any help you could provide would be appreciated!

**tl;dr: What causes theses errors, and how do I fix them?**

**PS:** I scrubbed the document of personal info. If you see any leftover, please let me know.

Thank you so much!

**Document**: https://v2.overleaf.com/read/shcftngvtpxs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `awesome-cv` has an error. The `cvitems` environment uses `\bullet` outside math-mode, thus you have a `Missing $ inserted` error. To fix it you have to redefine the `cvitems` (and if you use it, `cvitemstwo`) environment to insert the `\bullet` in math-mode. Add this to your preamble, somewhere after the `\documentclass`:

```
\renewenvironment{cvitems}{%
  \vspace{-4.0mm}
  \begin{justify}
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=2ex, nosep, noitemsep, label=$\bullet$]
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
}{%
  \end{itemize}
  \end{justify}
  \vspace{-4.0mm}
}
\renewenvironment{cvitemstwo}{%
  \vspace{-4mm}
  \begin{justify}
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=8.5 ex, nosep, itemsep=0.3em label=$\bullet$]
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
}{%
  \end{itemize}
  \end{justify}
  \vspace{-2mm}
}
```

or you can use a `\textbullet`. Just replace `label=$\bullet$` by `label=\textbullet`. Or you can use any other symbol you like, just give the appropriate code for `label`.

Comment: You're a wizard, that worked! I have been trying to figure this out for way too long. Could you elaborate on why `\bullet` needs to be in math-mode?

Comment: @bvosk It has to be in math-mode because the glyph belongs to a math font. When you switch to math-mode you select the math font and use the glyph. If you are in text mode, TeX sees a math-mode glyph and says that a `$` is missing. The same will happen if you try to write, for example, `\pi`, or an non-escaped `_` or `^` outside math mode. You could also use `\textbullet`, which I didn't know existed until now :)

Comment: Very informative. Thanks for circling back for me!